# Including a Maven product from different directory into project directoy

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin

My question I have a project in x directory and another maven project in x/y directory. Now how can I get the jar files be generated for a project in x directory from a project in y directory

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`jar-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/index.html) within a project's pom.xml to modify the location of the output jar -

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.2</version>
      <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>/x/y</outputDirectory> <!-- specify the relative desired path here -->
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```